# convert json from one form to another in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, django, list

I have got a response after altering a list. My response looks something like this :

```
{
 "response": [
    {
     "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
     "logs": [
         {
             "exception": "IllegalAgrumentsException",
             "count": 1
         }
      ]
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
        "logs": [
         {
             "exception": "NullPointerException",
             "count": 2
         }
     ]
   },..
```

I want the result to be something like this:-

```
 "response": [
     {
       "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
       "logs": [
          {
              "exception": "IllegalAgrumentsException",
              "count": 1
          },
          {
              "exception": "NullPointerException",
              "count": 2
          } ]
   }
```

How can I merge logs together like above in python?

Comment: Is this you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188028/convert-list-to-a-particular-json-in-python/ Do you have multiple accounts?

Comment: That's my project partner

Comment: Okay, fine... My answer there shouldn't be able to generate a response like you have, unless it's being misused.

Comment: You aren't specifying what to do with the counts, though; should the lists just be concatenated, or the counts summed up?

Comment: just concatenated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with the [other part of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188028/convert-list-to-a-particular-json-in-python/), it would be `defaultdict` time... but we'll need `OrderedDict` here to keep the original timestamp order.

```
import collections

input_data = [
    {
        "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
        "logs": [{"exception": "IllegalAgrumentsException", "count": 1}],
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
        "logs": [{"exception": "NullPointerException", "count": 2}],
    },
]

logs_by_timestamp = collections.OrderedDict()

for datum in input_data:
    logs_by_timestamp.setdefault(datum["timestamp"], []).extend(datum["logs"])

output_data = [
    {"timestamp": timestamp, "logs": logs}
    for (timestamp, logs) in logs_by_timestamp.items()
]

print(output_data)
```

outputs (formatted)

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
        "logs": [
            {"exception": "IllegalAgrumentsException", "count": 1},
            {"exception": "NullPointerException", "count": 2},
        ],
    }
]
```

Comment: `list indices must be integers or slices, not str` error at line `for datum..`

Comment: Nope, that error doesn't come from this code. If your list is still in that `"response": [...]` thing, you'll naturally have to unwrap that first: `input_data = response["response"]` or whatnot.

Comment: yes, I saw that. But my order of data is changed totally. I want my order of output data to remain same input data

Comment: Edited to use `OrderedDict` instead.

Answer (score 1):

considering your situatuation..

check out the below patch

```
_dict = {
    "response": [
        {
            "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
            "logs": [
                {
                    "exception": "IllegalAgrumentsException",
                    "count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
            "logs": [
                {
                    "exception": "NullPointerException",
                    "count": 2
                }
            ]
        }]}

_final = {}
for _dict in _dict.get('response'):
    if not _dict.get('timestamp') in _final:
        _final[_dict.get('timestamp')] = {
            'timestamp': _dict.get('timestamp'),
            'logs': []
        }
    _final[_dict.get('timestamp')]['logs'] += _dict.get('logs')

_result ={'response': list(_final.values())}

print(_result)
```

which will print ...

```
{
  'response': [
    {
      'timestamp': '21:15-21:30',
      'logs': [
        {
          'exception': 'IllegalAgrumentsException',
          'count': 1
        },
        {
          'exception': 'NullPointerException',
          'count': 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: My response is a list not dict

Comment: for your response being a list... 
replace: 
_result ={'response': list(_final.values())} with _result = list(_final.values())

Answer (score 0):

```py
response = [
    {
        "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
        "logs": [{"exception": "IllegalAgrumentsException", "count": 1}],
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
        "logs": [{"exception": "NullPointerException", "count": 2}],
    },
]
```

```
final = []
for k,v in groupby(response, lambda x:x.pop('timestamp')):
    final.append({
        'timestamp':k,
        'logs':reduce(
        lambda x,y:  {'logs':y['logs']+x['logs']},      
        [*v]
        )['logs']
    })
print(final)
```

```
Output 
[
    {
        "timestamp": "21:15-21:30",
        "logs": [
            {"exception": "IllegalAgrumentsException", "count": 1},
            {"exception": "NullPointerException", "count": 2},
        ],
    }
]
```